# Linear Sort of a 2D Array

Tags: c, sorting

I am a newbie to C programming and was trying to prepare some sorting programs. I made the program of linear/ normal Sorting.

Now I want to make a program to sort 2D array.
i.e. If the matrix is

```
4  6  1
3  2  9
5  7  8
```

Then the result should be

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

Comment: Can you post how you're allocating your array memory? Depending on how you're doing it, you might be able to do the easy way. ALSO: Which is this, C or C++?

Comment: Apparently, except for the way values are fetched/stored, there's no difference to the linear method you already wrote. Adapt your previous code to the new requirement -- that's what programming is, after all :)

Comment: Seconding the C/C++ question: Pick one.

Comment: As a first look, it needs a backtracking algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your 2D array to be sorted row-wise, which happens to be the order in which multidimensional arrays are stored in C, you could pretend it is a 1D array and sort it that way.

Assuming you have a function `void sort(int[], int size);` that takes a pointer to the first element of a 1D array and its size, you could do

```
int a[3][3] = {{4,6,1}, {3,2,9}, {5,7,8}};
sort(&a[0][0], 9);
```

Naturally, this only works for true 2D arrays, not for arrays of pointers, which is how dynamically allocated 2D arrays are often implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much the same function, if you are allocating the memory as a regular multi-dimensional declaration... Since multi-dimensional arrays are stored in memory row after row and each row is just a regular array.

Just pass to the function the address of the first element of the matrix (usually `name_of_the_matrix[0]`) and the number of elements in the matrix.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bubble-Sort: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort) and go through the array with a for-loop.

Comment: False, you can *never* use bubble sort.  Not if you want to keep your job.

Comment: Bubble sort only has value as an example of hot NOT to sort something.  It is taught first because it has so many issues that it's easy to pick it apart as the worst possible means of sorting something.  Only extremely silly sorting routines (like StoogeSort, or RandomSort) can beat bubble sort's flaws. As a result, any programming professional should never recommend a bubble sort. http://tinsology.net/2009/06/bubble-sort-is-never-the-answer/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: As a learning project with N = 3, the bubble sort will do the job just fine.  It is a stepping stone to the more useful ones.

Comment: Even selection sort has better performance, bubble sort is only taught to show something so bad that everything else looks good by comparison.  It's the computer science strawman of sorting algorithms.  Some people mistake this "first presentation" as being the foundation of sorting (elevating it to the one sorting algorithm they'll never forget).

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to sort the array based on cell ordering, so you need to have a way to get a cell based on it's order and a way to write a cell based on it's ordering.

```
int getCellOrder(int x, int y) {
   return x*(x_width) + y;
}

int getXpos(int cellOrder) {
   return cellOrder / x_width;
}

int getYpos(int cellOrder) {
   return cellOrder % x_width;
}
```

With those two elements, you can now grab any two cell orders for your array, and the values they reference.

```
int valueAt(int cellOrder) {
   return array[getXpos(cellOrder)][getYpos(cellOrder];
}
```

How you compare the orders and how you swap them now becomes a simple 1D array problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take the C++ approach and do the following while representing your matrix in 1D:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(int arg, char **argv) {
  int matrix[] = {4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5, 7, 8};
  vector<int> matvec (matrix, matrix + sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(int));
  sort(matvec.begin(), matvec.end());
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it like this given that you made an 2D array a[][] and the elements like me:

```
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 for(j=0;j<col;j++)
  for(k=0;k<row;k++)
   for(p=0;p<col;p++)
      if(a[i][j]>a[k][p])
      temp=a[i][j]; a[i][j]=a[k][p]; a[k][p]=temp;
```