# How to sort an 2D array in a descending way

Tags: c

How can i sort an 2D array in a descending way, without using pointers im still a beginner.

Fore example if i input an 2D array 2x2. With the following elements:
2 3
1 5
The output should be:
5 3
2 1

Comment: Did you bother to search this very site for `[sorting][2d][array]` ? Just saying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Sort of a 2D Array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185302/linear-sort-of-a-2d-array-in-c)

Comment: No shortcuts, learn how to write the `qsort` "compare" function and then simply call `qsort` to sort your array. Well worth the time to learn. It will save you an untold number of hours in the future compared to trying to *roll-your-own* sort function every time you need to sort (and it will be a lot (1) faster, and (2) less error prone.)

Comment: "nput an 2D array 2x2. With the following elements: 2 3 1 5 The output should be: 5 3 2 1" --> that sounds like a 1D sort.

Comment: 1. Yes i searched the site and all of the answers were done by pointers or in built functions. 2. Yeah the tasks are the same but they use in built functions i want to do this the hardest way possible to find the meaning of how its done. 3. Look at 1. 4. I couldnt click enter to get it in the next row so it really looks like a simple array :D .

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
 for(j=0;j<col;j++)
  for(k=0;k<row;k++)
   for(p=0;p<col;p++)
    if(a[i][j]>a[k][p])
      temp=a[i][j]; a[i][j]=a[k][p]; a[k][p]=temp;
```

This worked for me

Comment: I doubt that this works correctly, except in very few cases. Try your code on an array that is already sorted ...

Comment: I tried this code 10 times couldnt find any error everything runs smooth with every possible array. Just switch the lesser sign.